# refer multiple external csv files returns #VALUE! error in vlookup function Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula

I have a master excel sheet,abc.xls and I need it to refer to columns found in 2 other csx files:def.csv and ghj.csv.I tried using the VLOOKUP function:

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,[def.csv]def!R2C15:R439C15+[ghi.csv]ghi!R2C9:R1248C9,1,FALSE)
```

where `F2` is a column in abc.xls and `R2C15:R439C15` are the rows referred in `def.csv` and `R2C9:R1248C9` are the rows referred in `ghi.csv`. However, when I tried this formula in the `master copy(abc.xls)`,it returns a `#VALUE!` error. As I am not too sure on how to refer to multiple external csv files, could anybody guide me on how to modify this formula?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `+`. .csv is irrelevant. If you want to check whether a value is present in two different places you could use two LOOKUPs or combine the two reference lists into one.